# Continuity and differentiability on a closed subset of a closed interval.

Tags: real-analysis

We know that a function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at a point $c\in(a,b)$ if and only if the following limit $$\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-a}$$ exists, or in other words we can also say that if and only if the following one-sided limits $$\lim_{x\to c^-}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-a}\text{ and }\lim_{x\to c^+}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-a}$$ exists and both are equal. We also know that $f$ is said to be differentiable at the end point $a$ if and only if the following one-sided limit $$\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$ exists and $f$ is said to be differentiable at the end point $b$ if and only if the following one-sided limit $$\lim_{x\to b^-}\frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}$$ exists.

Firstly, assume that $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$. So, can we conclude that $$\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)=f(a)\text{ and }\lim_{x\to b^+}f(x)=f(b).$$

Now assume that it is said that $f$ is differentiable on the closed interval $[d,e],$ where $a<d<e<b$. This obviously means that both the left hand derivative and the right hand derivative of $f$ exists at each point $c_1\in(d,e)$. Now from the above definitions, we can surely conclude that the right hand derivative of $f$ exists at the point $d$ and the left hand derivative of $f$ exists at the point $e$.

But, can we also conclude that the left hand derivative of $f$ at the point $d$ also exists and it is equal to it's corresponding right hand derivative? Similarly, can we also conclude that the right hand derivative of $f$ exists at the point $e$, and it is equal to it's corresponding left hand derivative? Even if these are not true, can we still conclude that $f$ is continuous at the points $d$ and $e$? Even if this is not true, can we still conclude that $$\lim_{x\to d^+}f(x)=f(d)\text{ and }\lim_{x\to e^-}f(x)=f(e)?$$

Comment: Think about $$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & x \in [a,d)\\
1, & x \in [d,e]\\
0, & x \in (e,b]
\end{cases}
$$.

Comment: @Renard,this is a really nice example. It is evident by definition that, $f$ is differentiable on the interval $[d,e]$. But $f$ is neither differentiable at the point $d$ nor at the point $e$. Also, $f$ is not continuous at the points $d$ and $e$. But, $f$ is continuous on the interval $[d,e]$. Also the function is right continuous at the point $a$ and left continuous at the point $b$.